# Equivalence of vector operations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, solution-verification

I am looking for a clarification. I have worked out that $$\underline\nabla(\underline m\cdot\underline r r^{-3})=-\underline\nabla \times (\underline m \times \underline r r^{-3})$$

Where $\underline m$ is a constant vector, $\underline r$ is the position vector and r is the magnitude of the position vector

Is this correct?

Comment: Show your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [cross/dot product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Dot_product_rule)

$$\nabla\times(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}) = (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B})\mathbf{A}-(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A})\mathbf{B}+(\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A}-(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla )\mathbf{B}$$

$$\nabla(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B})= \mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{B} +\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{A}$$

$$\therefore\quad\nabla\times(\mathbf{m}\times\mathbf{r}/r^3)=(\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{r}/r^3))\mathbf{m}-\mathbf{m}\cdot\nabla(\mathbf{r}/r^3)$$

$$\nabla(\mathbf{m}\cdot\mathbf{r}/r^3)=\mathbf{m}\cdot\nabla(\mathbf{r}/r^3)$$

One can see that $-\nabla\times(\mathbf{m}\times\mathbf{r}/r^3)$ differs from $\nabla(\mathbf{m}\cdot\mathbf{r}/r^3)$ by the extra term $(\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{r}/r^3))\mathbf{m}$.

Comment: Lovely, and $\underline m(\underline \nabla \cdot \underline r r^{-3})=m((\underline \nabla \cdot \underline r )r^{-3}+(\underline \nabla r^{-3})\cdot \underline r)=m(3r^{-3}-3r^{-3})=0$